# Border-radius for IE7 & IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am working in cakephp and want to do some css style. The problem is with Internet Explorer. Currently i want to make css border-radius work properly in IE7 & IE8. The css i am using is

```
#lastcol
{
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    min-height:630px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

This is one `div` whose border-radius i want to make it work in IE also. For this i am using `behavior : url(/PIE.htc);`. I have already added the `PIE.js` script. The moment i add the behavior feature in `#lastcol` for doing rounded corners in IE the background vanishes. I have used this feature for doing rounded corners in css for some segments and this is working good but for certain cases like the above one it is not working.

I am not understanding what the issue is exactly. Why the background image or background color is removed immediately after adding `behavior : url(/PIE.htc);` for some `div` only whereas for others this is working perfectly. Please suggest whats needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

You will probably need to add `position: relative;` to the div or give it a z-index.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to create that element with javascript :

```
document.createElement("element");
```